# Why does using torch.normal().to('cuda') give an error RuntimeError: CUDA error: an illegal memory access was encountered?

Tags: python, pytorch

My environment

```
Package                 Version
----------------------- ------------
absl-py 2.0.0
blessed 1.20.0
cachetools 5.3.2
captum 0.6.0
certifi 2022.12.7
charset-normalizer 3.3.1
colour 0.1.5
cycler 0.11.0
Cython 3.0.5
dlib 19.24.0
fonttools 4.38.0
future 0.18.3
google-auth 2.23.4
google-auth-oauthlib 0.4.6
gpustat 1.1.1
grpcio 1.59.2
idna 3.4
importlib-metadata 6.7.0
joblib 1.3.2
kiwisolver 1.4.5
Markdown 3.4.4
MarkupSafe 2.1.3
matplotlib 3.5.3
numpy 1.21.6
nvidia-ml-py 12.535.108
oauthlib 3.2.2
packaging 23.2
pandas 1.1.5
patsy 0.5.3
Pillow 9.5.0
pip 22.3.1
protobuf 3.20.3
psutil 5.9.6
pyasn1 0.5.0
pyasn1-modules 0.3.0
pycocotools 2.0.7
pyparsing 3.1.1
python-dateutil 2.8.2
pytz 2023.3.post1
requests 2.31.0
requests-oauthlib 1.3.1
rsa 4.9
rtpt 0.0.4
scikit-learn 1.0.2
scipy 1.7.3
seaborn 0.12.2
setproctitle 1.3.3
setuptools 65.6.3
six 1.16.0
statsmodels 0.13.5
tensorboard 2.11.2
tensorboard-data-server 0.6.1
tensorboard-logger 0.1.0
tensorboard-plugin-wit 1.8.1
Tensorboard dx 2.6.2.2
threadpoolctl 3.1.0
torch 1.6.0+cu101
torchsummary 1.5.1
torchvision 0.7.0+cu101
tqdm 4.66.1
typing_extensions 4.7.1
urllib3 2.0.7
wcwidth 0.2.9
Werkzeug 2.2.3
wheel 0.38.4
zipp 3.15.0
```

I ran into a problem where I wanted to use GPU to output my tensors. I noticed that my error was due to the input and the other tensors not being on the same device anymore, and the positioning error pointed to f.inear (input, self.weight, self.bias). So I changed
`self.weight = Parameter(torch.Tensor(out_features, in_features))` to `self.weight = Parameter(torch.Tensor(out_features, in_features).to('cuda'))`, Also changed `self.bias = Parameter(torch.Tensor(out_features))` to
`self.bias = Parameter(torch.Tensor(out_features).to('cuda'))`, It's supposed to be just a matter of modifying the input to run on cuda, but the above error occurred while I was trying to change it. How can I modify it to run on cuda?
The first paragraph below is where I modified it. The second paragraph is where I changed the input from `slots = torch.normal(mu, sigma)` to `slots = torch.normal(mu, sigma).to('cuda')`.

```
python
class Linear(Module):
    r"""Applies a linear transformation to the incoming data: :math:`y = xA^T + b`

    Args:
        in_features: size of each input sample
        out_features: size of each output sample
        bias: If set to ``False``, the layer will not learn an additive bias.
            Default: ``True``

    Shape:
        - Input: :math:`(N, *, H_{in})` where :math:`*` means any number of
          additional dimensions and :math:`H_{in} = \text{in\_features}`
        - Output: :math:`(N, *, H_{out})` where all but the last dimension
          are the same shape as the input and :math:`H_{out} = \text{out\_features}`.

    Attributes:
        weight: the learnable weights of the module of shape
            :math:`(\text{out\_features}, \text{in\_features})`. The values are
            initialized from :math:`\mathcal{U}(-\sqrt{k}, \sqrt{k})`, where
            :math:`k = \frac{1}{\text{in\_features}}`
        bias:   the learnable bias of the module of shape :math:`(\text{out\_features})`.
                If :attr:`bias` is ``True``, the values are initialized from
                :math:`\mathcal{U}(-\sqrt{k}, \sqrt{k})` where
                :math:`k = \frac{1}{\text{in\_features}}`

    Examples::

        >>> m = nn.Linear(20, 30)
        >>> input = torch.randn(128, 20)
        >>> output = m(input)
        >>> print(output.size())
        torch.Size([128, 30])
    """
    __constants__ = ['in_features', 'out_features']
    in_features: int
    out_features: int
    weight: Tensor

    def __init__(self, in_features: int, out_features: int, bias: bool = True) -> None:
        super(Linear, self).__init__()
        self.in_features = in_features
        self.out_features = out_features
        self.weight = Parameter(torch.Tensor(out_features, in_features).to('cuda'))
        if bias:
            self.bias = Parameter(torch.Tensor(out_features).to('cuda'))
        else:
            self.register_parameter('bias', None)
        self.reset_parameters()

    def reset_parameters(self) -> None:
        init.kaiming_uniform_(self.weight, a=math.sqrt(5))
        if self.bias is not None:
            fan_in, _ = init._calculate_fan_in_and_fan_out(self.weight)
            bound = 1 / math.sqrt(fan_in)
            init.uniform_(self.bias, -bound, bound)

    def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
        print("input.device", input.device)
        print("self.weight.device", self.weight.device)
        print("self.bias.device", self.bias.device)
        return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)

    def extra_repr(self) -> str:
        return 'in_features={}, out_features={}, bias={}'.format(
            self.in_features, self.out_features, self.bias is not None
        )
```

```
class SlotAttention(nn.Module):
    """
    Implementation from https://github.com/lucidrains/slot-attention by lucidrains.
    """
    def __init__(self, num_slots, dim, iters=3, eps=1e-8, hidden_dim=128):
        super().__init__()
        self.num_slots = num_slots
        self.iters = iters
        self.eps = eps
        self.scale = dim ** -0.5

        self.slots_mu = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1, 1, dim))
        # self.slots_log_sigma = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1, 1, dim))
        self.slots_log_sigma = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1, 1, dim)).abs()

        self.project_q = nn.Linear(dim, dim)
        self.project_k = nn.Linear(dim, dim)
        self.project_v = nn.Linear(dim, dim)

        self.gru = nn.GRUCell(dim, dim)

        hidden_dim = max(dim, hidden_dim)

        self.mlp = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(dim, hidden_dim),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Linear(hidden_dim, dim)
        )

        self.norm_inputs = nn.LayerNorm(dim, eps=1e-05)
        self.norm_slots = nn.LayerNorm(dim, eps=1e-05)
        self.norm_mlp = nn.LayerNorm(dim, eps=1e-05)

        # dummy initialisation
        self.attn = 0

    def forward(self, inputs, num_slots=None):
        b, n, d = inputs.shape
        n_s = num_slots if num_slots is not None else self.num_slots

        mu = self.slots_mu.expand(b, n_s, -1)
        sigma = self.slots_log_sigma.expand(b, n_s, -1)
        slots = torch.normal(mu, sigma).to('cuda')
        inputs = self.norm_inputs(inputs)
        k, v = self.project_k(inputs), self.project_v(inputs)

        for _ in range(self.iters):
            slots_prev = slots

            slots = self.norm_slots(slots)
            q = self.project_q(slots)

            dots = torch.einsum('bid,bjd->bij', q, k) * self.scale
            attn = dots.softmax(dim=1) + self.eps
            attn = attn / attn.sum(dim=-1, keepdim=True)

            updates = torch.einsum('bjd,bij->bid', v, attn)

            slots = self.gru(
                updates.reshape(-1, d),
                slots_prev.reshape(-1, d)
            )

            slots = slots.reshape(b, -1, d)
            slots = slots + self.mlp(self.norm_mlp(slots))

        self.attn = attn

        return slots
```

Has anyone ever had a similar problem？I would appreciate it if you could help me.

I tried changing the input to input= input.to('cuda'), but still got the same error.

Comment: What is your full error message?

Comment: Can you post specific values for `mu` and `sigma` that reliably reproduce the error on your end?

Comment: It may be that *CUDA is out of memory* you get `Runtime error.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, thanks for the attention, this is the first time I've ever posted an issue on overstack. I have solved this problem and it should not be CUDA. I noticed that there are some variables in the code to create new tensors. It seems that when a new tensor is created, it seems to default to the cpu if it is not specified on the machine. My solution is as follows.

Comment: Firstly, because the source code has many codes about device specifying cpu or cuda, it is difficult for me to find the error, so I remove all the codes about device specifying cpu or cuda.

Comment: Step 2, in order to run on cuda, this time I only specify the input and network to cuda, for example add to('cuda') code, then run to see the error.

Comment: Step 3, based on the error, I found a few places where I created a new tensor, and I added to('cuda') again. The problem seems to be solved. But there is still a question, why does torch.normal().to('cuda') give an error if I can append to the newly created tensor, which is supposed to be a tensor in theory?

Comment: I printed mu and sigma. They are tensors of size [20, 10, 64]. Could they be too big and cause an error? Because I tried the small tensor torch.normal(mean=torch.arange(4.),std=torch.arange(1.,0.6,-0.1)).to('cuda'), it seemed to work.

Comment: mu=tensor([[[-1.1308, -0.2085,  0.4386,  ...,  0.1549, -0.9338,  1.2848],
         ...,
         [-1.1308, -0.2085,  0.4386,  ...,  0.1549, -0.9338,  1.2848]]],
       grad_fn=<ExpandBackward>)
sigma=tensor([[[0.6305, 0.7653, 0.0254,  ..., 0.8900, 0.0874, 1.8087],
         [0.6305, 0.7653, 0.0254,  ..., 0.8900, 0.0874, 1.8087],
         ...,
         [0.6305, 0.7653, 0.0254,  ..., 0.8900, 0.0874, 1.8087]]],
       grad_fn=<ExpandBackward>)

Comment: The grad_fn=<ExpandBackward> at the end of these two tensors may be the reason, because I tried tensors of the same size again, the only difference is that there is no grad_fn=<ExpandBackward>, and they work.